# WinJs Or Cordova local html navigation

Tags: html, cordova, permissions, navigation, winjs

Is there a way to navigate to index.html which stored in local folder from Cordova or WinJS html page?

I heard that you can use MSApp.addPublicLocalApplicationUri function to allow remote access to local, but I cannot figure it out..

I want to navigate top localFolder and not to installed location.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, found an answer here:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/3dea95bb-a75e-47c5-ac9a-472b4870a47a/can-i-use-msappaddpubliclocalapplicationuri-to-navigate-to-html-pages-that-live-in-my-apps-local

it's not possible